# Http POST in order to Upload a file and send a JsonString --- send in ReactJs and Receive in Java

Tags: java, reactjs, httprequest, multipartform-data

I have a to send (upload) a file and send a JsonString in my ReactJs FrontEnd.
The BackEnd is a Java Tomcat.

Code in ReactJs:

```
                    const formData = new FormData();
                    formData.append('file', selectedFile);                    
                    formData.append( 'jsonstring', MY_JSONSTRING );                    


                    req = new Request(PARAMETRI_URL, {
                        method: 'post',
                        headers: new Headers({ "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"}),
                        body: formData
                    });
```

Code in Java:

```
             @MultipartConfig
             protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)  {
                    ..........
                    final Part PART_Json = request.getPart("jsonstring");
                    final Part PART_file = request.getPart("file");
```

It doesn't work!!!

I tried this solution using getPart(), but I don't know if it is the right one.

My target is: the ReactJs FrontEnd send a file and a JsonString to  Java BackEnd

I found many posts here, but not with this specific case. I did many tentatives, with differents headers, content-type, ecc...

Can somebody add the piece of codes in both ReactJs and Java side?

- in ReactJs: how to build 'req',
- in Java: how to process 'request' in
  order to extract the jsonstring and the file

Answer (score 0):

I solved using the following post:

[How to send a file from JavaScript to a Java WebService](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33631293/how-to-send-a-file-from-javascript-to-a-java-webservice/33690430#33690430)

At the end of the story, if you need multipart, in javascript/ReactJs you need to use 'XMLHttpRequest()', no way by 'new Request(...)' followed by 'fetch...'.